# Regex test for US/Canada long distance phone number?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this regex tester:

```
/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/.test(value);
```

which works great with the following cases:

```
123-456-7890
123 456-7890
123-456 7890
(123)-456-7890
123 456 7890
```

But fails completely when +1 is added for long distance call phone number within the US/Canada:

```
+1 123-456-7890
1 123-456-7890
11234567890
+1 (123)-456-7890
1 123 456 7890
```

How do I add those cases?

Comment: `/^(\+?1 ?)?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give this a try:

```
/^(\+?1 ?)?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/.test(value);
```

I prepended your regex with `(\+?1 ?)?`

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to use a library to do such testings, the best I've found so far is google's libphonenumber (available in various languages, javascript included). If using a whole library is not an alternative for you, you can always look at the source code to find the right regexes for canada numbers ([here](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/source/browse/trunk/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/metadatalite.js) the source for the metadata)